# Android - HangMan App Errors

Tags: android

I do not understand why my app crashes in this code, and there is no error or stacktrace in logcat.

```
package org.concordacademy.hangman;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayScreen extends Activity {

    // The String Below will tell Console/LogCat the processes of The PlayScreen Activity

    private final String PS = "Play Screen";
    private char[] secretWord;
    private char[] displayedWord;
    // Below is an array of the Letters already guessed.
    private ArrayList<Character> chosenLetters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playscreen);
        Log.i(PS, "Loading Play Screen.");

        startGame();
    }

    // Read Text File entitled wordsEn.txt 
        public String readFromFile() {
            String words = "";
            // Array List That Words being added to
            ArrayList<String> wordLineArray = new ArrayList<String>();

            try { 
                InputStream inputstream = openFileInput("wordsEn.txt");
                if (inputstream != null) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                        wordLineArray.add(receiveString);
                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    }
                    inputstream.close();
                    // Possible pointless code below
                    words = stringBuilder.toString();
                }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
            }

            //R Generator for Strings in wordLineArray 
            //String secretWordString = wordLineArray.get(getRandomNumber(0, wordLineArray.size()));
            String secretWordString = "HelloWorld";
            secretWord = secretWordString.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
                displayedWord[i] = '-';
            }
            return words;

        }

        // Choose a random number that is assigned to a corresponding String in ArrayList

        public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
            int number = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
            return number;

        }

        public void startGame() {
            readFromFile();
            String secretWordString = "HelloWorld";
            secretWord = secretWordString.toCharArray();
            displayedWord = new char[secretWord.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
                displayedWord[i] = '-';
            }

        }

        public void findLetters(String guess) {
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
                // Change Guess to CharArray and 0 Index.
                if (!guess.isEmpty()) {
                    if (guess.toCharArray()[0] == secretWord[i]) {
                        Log.i(PS, "Correct Guess");
                        displayedWord[i] = guess.toCharArray()[0]; 
                    }
                }
            }
            // Add Guess to the already chosen letter array
            if (!guess.isEmpty()) {
                chosenLetters.add(guess.toCharArray()[0]);
            }
        }

        public boolean checkWin() {
            if (displayedWord == secretWord) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void guessButtonClick(View v) {
            TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayedWord);
            displayText.setText(displayedWord.toString());
            EditText inputGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textField);
            String guess = inputGuess.getText().toString();
            findLetters(guess);

        }

}
```

Secondly, When I use the text view to display dashes, instead, it doesn't display anything and when i submit a letter it shows a memory location. I know I am not providing much information, but I am deeply confused. I am also reading a txt file and storing it into an array, and it vital I need it.

Comment: Your app crashes... WHEN?

Comment: When I push to this activity. There is something wrong in this file that does not let it run.

Comment: Try to put breakpoints and run step by step.

Comment: The error happens when I run readFromFile() in startGame(). I am unsure why.

Comment: How do you know there's an error if there's no error in stacktrace or logcat?

Comment: The app crashes when I run it.

Comment: Then there has to be an error in your LogCat or you're not reading it properly. While I can point out a number of things that are odd with your code, we can't do much to help if you don't show that stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the `displayedWord` variable. It is being initialized after you use it in `startGame()`

```
readFromFile();  // here you use it
//...
displayedWord = new char[secretWord.length];  // here you initialize it
```

You need to initialize it first, and THEN used it!